# Logging HTTPS hits before they complete with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, java

I've got a SVN repository that's served up over HTTPS (via Apache).  Well, some requests seem to cause the SVN server to freak out and eat 100% CPU.  I say "seem to" because the SVN server goes nuts before Apache logs the connection, so I can't see what URL is being hit.  The client is IntelliJ, and as far as I can tell it can't log exactly what it's sending to me.

How the heck do I debug this?  I've got an idea of what someone clicks in IntelliJ to make the server go nuts, but I'd really like to see the exact query.  Is there some option to Apache to make it log requests before they finish?  Or... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try loading the `mod_status` Apache module to monitor what requests are happening.

In your `httpd.conf` add the following and restart Apache. You should then be able to go to `http://server/server-status` and view what Apache is processing.

```
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so 
ExtendedStatus On

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status`
</Location>
```

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'll try it, since it shouldn't have much impact on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to sniff the SSL connection with SSL Dump and decrypt the traffic with the private key.

> If linked with OpenSSL, ssldump can
>   display certificates in decoded form
>   and decrypt traffic (provided that it
>   has the appropriate keying material).
>   Again, OpenSSL may be installed on
>   your system. Otherwise you can obtain
>   it from http://www.openssl.org

http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/

Wireshark can do that too.